# Solve for square root of imaginary number in standard form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am in precalc/trig and have a question that reads :

> $X^2 + 2i = 0$. Solve for all solutions and leave answer in standard form.

Any help is appreciated from anyone who knows how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=a+ib$ then 
$$X^2+2i=(a^2-b^2)+2i(ab+1)=0\Leftrightarrow a^2=b^2\;, \; ab=-1.$$
Can you take it form here?